# Is there a more concise version of the CASE WHEN foo.bar IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END paradigm?

Tags: sql, sas

The goal is simply to check whether a field is `NULL` or not, yielding a value of `1` when the field is not `NULL`, and `0` otherwise. I can't use `COALESCE` here, because if the field isn't `NULL`, I just want to return `1`, not the value of the field.

I have a gut feeling that there's already a function that does this - something like `NULL_STATUS_INTEGER(foo.bar)`, for example - instead of needing to write out the full `CASE` statement of `CASE WHEN foo.bar IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`. I'm not saying that the `CASE` version is absurdly long, but I just find it strange that there's not a shorter way to do this.

I'm primarily interested in solutions that aren't confined to one SQL vendor, but I happen to be using SAS, if there happens to be a SAS-specific way to do this in `PROC SQL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparisons are also boolean, return a true/false

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, name = 'Alfred' as flag
from sashelp.class;
quit;

data want;
set sashelp.class;
flag = (name = 'Alfred');

run;
```

EDIT:

Another option is to use IFN()/IFC(), which factor in three conditions, FALSE, TRUE, MISSING. [IFN()/IFC()](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0l3n5z2h31h7wn1fmnqd33ibhap.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) can be used in SQL or a data step in SAS.

```
x = ifc(name="Alfred", 1, 0, .);
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know specifying `foo.bar IS NOT NULL` as a field, all by itself, was legal SQL. Just tested (to make sure it works in SAS as well as in ANSI SQL) and that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Beware that in SQL comparisons return three possible values, so this solution may be flawed. SQL can return `TRUE`,`FALSE`, or `UNKNOWN`. That's why the long version (the one you don't like) may be correct.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue with SAS, it treats NULL and missing the same. If you're using pass through SQL that may result in a different value. Another option is to use IFN()/IFC().